# Spring bean creation confusion

Tags: spring

I am new to spring. I have a confusion in spring beans is it necessary to make bean of all data members of class if not, then which data members should be made beans and which data members should not?
I shall be thankful. :)

Comment: You'd better rephrase your question. It's hard to understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776547/role-of-new-keyword-in-spring-framework). The answer I received makes sense, which I'll paraphrase here.

- If a class uses other beans to perform business logic in its own methods, then the class itself should also be made into a bean.
- If the class *does not use* other beans to perform business logic and really is just a POJO, then this class doesn't need to be configured as a bean.

If you have a more specific question based on your current use case, I suggest posting that as a separate question with more details and sample code.