# NullpointException in junit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

In my java spring mvc application, I face a NullPointerException in my junit test, all the classes are located in a certain package which i have addressed them as below in `main` method

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.model" })
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

then in `com.example.model` i have the following classes, and interface:

```
public interface DataService {

    int[] retrieveAllData();

}
```

The implementation is as below:

```
@Service
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {

    @Override
    public int[] retrieveAllData() {

        return new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
}
```

and then i used the service as below in another class:

```
public class SomeBussiness {

    @Autowired
    DataServiceImpl dataService;

    public int findTheGreat() {
        int[] res = dataService.retrieveAllData();
        return res[0];

    }
}
```

The i wrote a test to check the `findTheGreattest()` in the `SomeBussiness`  class:

```
public class SomeBussinessTest {

    @Test
    public void findTheGreatTest() {
        SomeBussiness sbi = new SomeBussiness();
        int res = sbi.findTheGreatest();
        assertEquals(1, res);
    }
}
```

But it complains with `NullPointException` in line

```
int[] res = dataService.retrieveAllData();
```

But, i have used `@Service`, and the `@Autowiered` to inject the `dataService`

How can i fix it?

---

Update:

I have added `@Service` the `SomeBussiness` class:

```
@Service
public class SomeBussiness {

    @Autowired
    DataServiceImpl dataService;

    public int findTheGreat() {
        int[] res = dataService.retrieveAllData();
        return res[0];

    }
}
```

and then add change the test as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)
public class SomeBussinessTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeBussiness sbi;

    @Test
    public void findTheGreatestTest() {
        assertEquals(1, sbi.findTheGreatest());

    }
}
```

and now it complains with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.SomeBussinessTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sbi'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.model.SomeBussiness' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: because of new keyword. when you create an instance using new, spring`s dependency will not take place, you will have to ensure passing the dependencies.

Comment: i don't get u. can u write an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of new keyword. when you create an instance using new, spring`s dependency injection will not take place, you will have to ensure passing the dependencies through constructor or setter.

```
   @Test
    public void findTheGreatTest() {
        SomeBussiness sbi = new SomeBussiness();
        sbi.setDataService(dbService);
        int res = sbi.findTheGreatest();
        assertEquals(1, res);
    }
```

Using `SpringRunner`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class)
public class SomeBussinessTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeBussiness sbi;

    @Test
    public void findTheGreatestTest() {
        assertEquals(1, sbi.findTheGreatest());

    }
}
```

This post clearly explains the role of new keyword :

[Role of new keyword in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776547/role-of-new-keyword-in-spring-framework)

Comment: @KamyarParastesh add `@Service` to public class SomeBussiness {} this class. not on SomeBussinessTest.

Comment: @KamyarParastesh still error ?? add the classes to ContextConfiguration to load the context. see the updated answer. if still error share the package structure

Comment: created pull request see the change. also updated the answer it worked.

Comment: it helped. But i still have another question, which i would write it, and teg u on it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Autowired in your classes is never triggered. First of all you need a JUnit runner which initializes all the test classes. Additionally you have to create the class under test through this runner instead of creating it by calling 'new':

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DemoApplication.class})
public class SomeBussinessTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeBussiness sbi;

    @Test
    public void findTheGreatTest() {
        int res = sbi.findTheGreatest();
        assertEquals(1, res);
    }
}
```